# PHP click to load in an other page

Tags: php

I am a PHP beginner and really need your help.

Ok lets try to make it easy.

I have 2 pages:

1) A index.php page with 4 different buttons:

-Paris

-Nice

-Bordeaux

-Lyon

2) A details.php page with a title and description.

What I want to do:

In index.php, when I click "Paris", i want to load the details.php page with the description of "Paris" that I have on the database.

In index.php, when I click "Nice", i want to load the details.php page with the description of "Nice" that I have on the database.

etc...

I know the form method POST technique to pass information but in this case it is not a form, just different buttons to load specific content from the database in an other page.

I hope I am clear enough.

Waiting for you answers !

Thanks for the reading.

Chloé

Answer (score 2):

Switch is better, and don't forget security

index.php

```
<a href="details.php?t=paris"><button>Paris</button></a>
<a href="details.php?t=nice"><button>Nice</button></a>
<a href="details.php?t=bordeaux"><button>Bordeaux</button></a>
<a href="details.php?t=lyon"><button>Lyon</button></a>
```

details.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET["t"]))
{
    $t = htmlentities($_GET["t"]);
    switch($t)
    {
        case "paris":
            $title = "Detail of $t";
            $text = "...";
            break;
        case "nice":
            $title "Detail of $t";
            $text = "...";
            break;
        case "bordeaux":
            $title "Detail of $t";
            $text = "...";
            break;
        case "lyon":
            $title "Detail of $t";
            $text = "...";
            break;
        default:
            $title = "You asked $t, but is an unknown town in our database";
            $text = "";
    }
}
?>
```

in head section

```
<html>
    <head>
    <?php echo "<title>$title</title>"; ?>
    </head>
```

in body section

```
    <body>
        <?php echo "$text"; ?>
    </body>
```

Note:
Also, you can try to use a templating engine, to simplify 
the clarity and mix (php+html)

Look for my example here :
[Quitting Smarty to do it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32982048/quitting-smarty-to-do-it-manually/34380085#34380085)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_GET requests.
In page 1 make links like http://example.com?name=paris

And in page 2 you can use:
$name = $_GET['name'];

for multiple values devide them with a &.
example: 
http://example.com?page=paris&limit=100&category=airports

Answer (score 0):

**index.php**

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="details.php?t=paris"><button>Paris</button></a>
<a href="details.php?t=nice"><button>Nice</button></a>
<a href="details.php?t=bordeaux"><button>Bordeaux</button></a>
<a href="details.php?t=lyon"><button>Lyon</button></a>
</body>
</html>
```

**details.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["t"]))
{
    if($_GET["t"]=="paris")
    {echo "Desc of Paris";}
    else if($_GET["t"]=="nice")
    {echo "Desc of Nice";}
    else if($_GET["t"]=="bordeaux")
    {echo "Desc of Bordeaux";}
    else if($_GET["t"]=="lyon")
    {echo "Desc of Lyon";}
    else{echo "Invalid Title!";}
}
else{echo "no get value found!";}
?>
```